# Dynamically growing Views

Tags: java, android

At that, I would like to ask for your help, how can I view more dynamically to create Android?
I saw somewhere that you need to create a View [] array, and it can be implemented in a "for" loop. It did not succeed. Here's the code which I tried.

```
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TextView atv[] = new TextView[2];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
        atv[i] = new TextView(this);
        atv[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
        atv[i].setText(i+"\n");
        atv[i].setTextSize(18);
        main.addView(atv[i]);
    }
```

Unfortunately it does not work! Can you help me ?!
Thank you very much for your help. Pengewap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "null" returns, but does not impose anything. However, if you do not cycle, but only one view was put into it prints the text to view.
However, the array numbering misspelled, did not start with 0. Fixed same is the case. If you know a better solution to create dynamic views also interested in!
Hello.

Comment: with findViewById (R.layout.main) the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why its doenst work? Probably findViewById(R.id.main) returns null.

You need to create the container.